# Retrieve the key value from a arrayObject

Tags: php, arrays, spl

This is my array:

```
ArrayObject::__set_state(
    array( 'data' => 
        array ( 
            'key1' => '573779', 
            'key2' => 'REF12345', 
            'key3' => '2010-07-12', 
            'key4' => '0000-00-00', 
            'key5' => '2010-07-12', 
            'key6' => '21654',
            'key7' => '0', 
            'key8' => ArrayObject::__set_state(array( )),
            'key9' => ArrayObject::__set_state(array( )), 
            'key10' => array ( ), 
            'key11' => array ( ), 
        )
)
```

I'm interested in finding out out how to retrieve any of the values for a key using SPL. Any of the keys can have arrays within arrays so I'm unsure how to obtain a value. I thought I may be able to use `->offsetGet('')` but this only retrieves from the top-most array.

Comment: If a key contains an array, do you need to be able to access any specific member of that subarray?  Also, that's a lot of keys.

Comment: Give an example of what you're trying to do, even if it doesn't currently work.

Comment: Yes, I potentially need to be able to access the array of a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) implements [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) so you can simply access them with the regular Array Notation, e.g.

```
echo $arrayObject['key1'];
```

In addition, ArrayObjects are [IteratorAggregates](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php), so you can iterate over them with `foreach` and decorate them with any of the [SPL iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php), including the [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)